# pyqt - populating QTableWidget with csv data

Tags: python, csv, pyqt, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget, i export the data from this table to a csv file.
But now, i want to Open a existing csv file and populate my table with this data. how can i do it?

This is my export code, i want a "populate" code, and i really dont know how to do it.. i know how to read a csv but i dont know how to populate my table with this csv data.

```
def export(self):
    nomeArquivo = "nomeArquivo"
    filename = unicode(QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Document - Choose Export File", nomeArquivo+".csv"))
    if not filename:
            return
    self.model.sort()
    fh = None
    try:

            fh = QFile(filename)
            if not fh.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly):                     
                raise IOError, unicode(fh.errorString())
            stream = QTextStream(fh)
            stream.setCodec("UTF-8")              
            for row in range(self.model.rowCount()):
                TSentence = self.model.data(
                self.model.index(row, TABELA.SENTENCE)).toString()
                TIrony = self.model.data(   
                self.model.index(row, TABELA.IRONY)).toString()

                stream  << "\""<< TSentence << "\"" << ";" << "\""<< TIrony <<"\"" <<"\n" 

    except (IOError, OSError), e:
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "Text - Error",
                "Failed to export: %s" % e)

    finally:
        if fh:
            fh.close()
    QMessageBox.warning(self, "Text - Export",
            "Successfully exported text to %s" % filename)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you could use the `csv` module here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import csv

import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, fileName, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.fileName = fileName

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)

        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        self.pushButtonLoad = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonLoad.setText("Load Csv File!")
        self.pushButtonLoad.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonLoad_clicked)

        self.pushButtonWrite = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonWrite.setText("Write Csv File!")
        self.pushButtonWrite.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonWrite_clicked)

        self.layoutVertical = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonLoad)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonWrite)

    def loadCsv(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, "rb") as fileInput:
            for row in csv.reader(fileInput):    
                items = [
                    QtGui.QStandardItem(field)
                    for field in row
                ]
                self.model.appendRow(items)

    def writeCsv(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, "wb") as fileOutput:
            writer = csv.writer(fileOutput)
            for rowNumber in range(self.model.rowCount()):
                fields = [
                    self.model.data(
                        self.model.index(rowNumber, columnNumber),
                        QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole
                    )
                    for columnNumber in range(self.model.columnCount())
                ]
                writer.writerow(fields)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonWrite_clicked(self):
        self.writeCsv(self.fileName)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonLoad_clicked(self):
        self.loadCsv(self.fileName)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow("/path/to/MyFile.csv")
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

PyQt5 version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import csv

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, fileName, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.fileName = fileName

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)

        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        self.pushButtonLoad = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonLoad.setText("Load Csv File!")
        self.pushButtonLoad.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonLoad_clicked)

        self.pushButtonWrite = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonWrite.setText("Write Csv File!")
        self.pushButtonWrite.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonWrite_clicked)

        self.layoutVertical = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonLoad)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonWrite)

    def loadCsv(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, "r") as fileInput:
            for row in csv.reader(fileInput):    
                items = [
                    QtGui.QStandardItem(field)
                    for field in row
                ]
                self.model.appendRow(items)

    def writeCsv(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, "w") as fileOutput:
            writer = csv.writer(fileOutput)
            for rowNumber in range(self.model.rowCount()):
                fields = [
                    self.model.data(
                        self.model.index(rowNumber, columnNumber),
                        QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole
                    )
                    for columnNumber in range(self.model.columnCount())
                ]
                writer.writerow(fields)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonWrite_clicked(self):
        self.writeCsv(self.fileName)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonLoad_clicked(self):
        self.loadCsv(self.fileName)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow("data.csv")
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @psytron You should introduce your alternate code solution as a new answer. Read [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/1677912)

Comment: I know its too late for this comment, but he was asking to populate `QTableWidget`, not `QTableView`.

Answer (score 3):

This is from a project of mine:

```
def setup_relation(self,rel):

    self.table.insertRow(0)

    for i in rel.header.attributes:
        item=QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setText(i)
        self.table.insertColumn(self.table.columnCount())
        self.table.setItem(0,self.table.columnCount()-1,item)

    for i in rel.content:
        self.table.insertRow(self.table.rowCount())
        for j in range(len(i)):
            item=QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setText(i[j])
            self.table.setItem(self.table.rowCount()-1,j,item)
```

Comment: Can QTableWidget use a model?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
 
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence, QCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QApplication, QFileDialog, QMenu, QTableView
 
 
class SEToolsTableView(QTableView):
 
    """QTableView class extended for SETools use."""
 
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(SEToolsTableView, self).__init__(parent)
 
        # set up right-click context menu
        self.save_csv_action = QAction("Save table to CSV...", self)
        self.menu = QMenu(self)
        self.menu.addAction(self.save_csv_action)
 
        # connect signals
        self.save_csv_action.triggered.connect(self.choose_csv_save_location)
 
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        self.menu.popup(QCursor.pos())
 
    def event(self, e):
        if e == QKeySequence.Copy or e == QKeySequence.Cut:
            datamodel = self.model()
 
            selected_text = []
            current_row = None
            current_col = None
            prev_row = None
            prev_col = None
            for index in sorted(self.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()):
                current_row = index.row()
                current_col = index.column()
 
                if prev_row is not None and current_row != prev_row:
                    selected_text.append('\n')
                elif prev_col is not None and current_col != prev_col:
                    selected_text.append('\t')
 
                selected_text.append(datamodel.data(index, Qt.DisplayRole))
 
                prev_row = current_row
                prev_col = current_col
 
            QApplication.clipboard().setText("".join(selected_text))
            return True
 
        else:
            return super(SEToolsTableView, self).event(e)
 
    def choose_csv_save_location(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save to CSV", "table.csv",
                                               "Comma Separated Values Spreadsheet (*.csv);;"
                                               "All Files (*)")[0]
 
        if filename:
            self.save_csv(filename)
 
    def save_csv(self, filename):
        """Save the current table data to the specified CSV file."""
 
        datamodel = self.model()
        row_count = datamodel.rowCount()
        col_count = datamodel.columnCount()
 
        with open(filename, 'w') as fd:
            writer = csv.writer(fd, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
 
            # write headers
            csv_row = []
            for col in range(col_count):
                csv_row.append(datamodel.headerData(col, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.DisplayRole))
 
            writer.writerow(csv_row)
 
            # write data
            for row in range(row_count):
                csv_row = []
 
                for col in range(col_count):
                    index = datamodel.index(row, col)
                    csv_row.append(datamodel.data(index, Qt.DisplayRole))
 
                writer.writerow(csv_row)
```