# Exporting as csv fits entirely in first cell

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, export-to-csv, qfiledialog

when i try to save my table (QTableWidget) as a csv file everything fits in the first cell from the excel file, how can i seperate each cell?  this is my saving function:

```
def save_text(self, table):
    path = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save CSV', os.getenv('HOME'), 'CSV(*.csv)')
    if path[0] != '':
        with open(path[0], 'w') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file, dialect='excel')
            for row in range(table.rowCount()):
                row_data = []
                for column in range(table.columnCount()):
                    item = table.item(row, column)
                    if item is not None:
                        row_data.append(item.text())
                    else:
                        row_data.append('')
                writer.writerow(row_data)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyqt - populating QTableWidget with csv data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416663/pyqt-populating-qtablewidget-with-csv-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
writer = csv.writer (csv_file, dialect = 'excel')
```

on

```
writer = csv.writer (csv_file, dialect = 'excel', delimiter = ';')
```